# How to convert a Map to Traverse

Tags: scala, scalaz

Is there a way to convert a `Map` to a `Traverse` ?

The aim is to call `map.traverseS(…)`.

Error is

```
<console>:16: error: value traverseS is not a member of    scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int]
```

Answer (score 2):

`Map` already has a `Traverse` instance:

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._
val m = Map(1 → "a", 2 → "b")
println(m.traverseS({ s => State({ f: Float => (f, s+f) }) }).run(1.0f))
```

prints

```
(1.0,Map(1 -> a1.0, 2 -> b1.0))
```

If you want to traverse the (key, value) pairs you can use `.toList`

```
println(m.toList.traverseS({
  case (k, v) => State({ f: Float => (f + k, v + f) }) }).run(1.0f))
```

prints

```
(4.0,List(a1.0, b2.0))
```

Comment: I have the following error :

error: could not find implicit value for parameter F0: scalaz.Traverse[scala.collection.immutable.Iterable]

              println(m.traverseS({ s => State({ f: Float => (f, s+f) }) }).run(1.0f))

Comment: Are you depending on scalaz 7.1? Do you have exactly the imports given here?

Comment: same imports. scalaz 7.0.4

Comment: Does `.toList` do what you want? Or you could copy the implementation from 7.1.

Comment: same issue with Scalaz 7.1.0 (scala 2.10.4)

Comment: Ah, my answer was for 2.11. Unapply doesn't seem to infer the right thing under 2.10. It's possible to translate the 2.11 code to 2.10 (i.e. explicitly passing the Unapply), but it's not pretty.

Comment: For some reason you have to give it some help with which type parameter to float. `type M[A] = Map[Int, A]; (m: M[String]).traverseS{ s => State{ f: Float => (f, s+f) } }.run(1.0f);`. Similar approach using type lambda did not work. `(m: ({type λ[a]=Map[Int,a]})#λ[String]).traverseS{ s => State{ f: Float => (f, s+f) } }.run(1.0f)`

Comment: @lmm In your example you import `scalaz._` and `Scalaz._`. What should I import precisely if I don't want to import everything?